# Representing a timetable in a database

Tags: sql, mysql, database-design, timetable

I want to represent a timetable on a mysql database.
I had the idea that I should have three tables:

1. a `classdetails` table - containing class capacity, classroom name, etc.
2. a `class_sessions` table with: start_time and end_time of session,
3. a `class_unit` table with: the name of the course (MAT003. et.c)

there would also be appropriate foreign keys in the `class_sessions` table and `class_unit` table.

Eventually I want to be able to query for a 'free' class (one that does not have a class presently, at the time of running of the query) and return its name e.g (Room 5b)

Will the tables I have listed be sufficient for the query at hand?

Any ideas how to make this better will be appreciated.

Comment: A free class is a class that doesn't have a class? Instead of thinking about tables, think about the kinds of facts you know about classes. Assuming a college, think in terms of "College catalog offers Algebra 101 in spring 2011." "Professor Smith will teach Algebra 101 in spring 2011." "Algebra 101 (Smith) meets Monday, Wednesday, Friday from 9:00 am to 11:00 am in spring 2011". "Algebra 101 (Smith) for spring 2011 will meet in room 5b." When you can express the facts, the tables will almost write themselves.

Comment: Thank you Catcall. Below is an attempt to express the facts as i see them:

Comment: Taking the example of math and roomx, there's algebra in room5b, there's calculus in room 5c, there's discreteMath in room5c, there's no class in room 5d , I want to do a query that returns room 5d.

Comment: In that case, it is not a timetable.  It is a room booking system. And you want the report in a grid, showing booked and free rooms. Correct ?

Comment: Thanks again Catcall, thanks PerformanceDBA. Yes correct its not a timetable the application is an sms based service to check for free rooms; but I need to be able to represent the timetable in the database to make these queries.and firstly i need to get the logic of the database right.Eventually yes, i might need to a grid on an html page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you said, but I'm still not 100% confident that what you said is what you want. :-)

```
CREATE TABLE rooms (
  room_num VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO rooms VALUES 
  ('5B'),
  ('5C'),
  ('5D');

CREATE TABLE class_rooms (
  class VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
  room_num VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT room_nm_fm_rooms FOREIGN KEY (room_num) REFERENCES rooms(room_num),
  PRIMARY KEY (class, room_num)
);

INSERT INTO class_rooms VALUES 
  ('Algebra', '5B'),
  ('Calculus','5C'),
  ('Discrete Math', '5C');
```

Having done that, one way to get the room number that's not in use is with a query using SELECT...WHERE...NOT IN. This probably isn't the fastest, but in my experience it's the easiest syntax to understand.

```
SELECT room_num 
FROM rooms 
WHERE room_num NOT IN (SELECT room_num FROM class_rooms);
```

Comment: Thanks, Catcall, I think this is what I am looking for.Let me try this out.I'll let you know if it works.